# Android Seekbar with markers

Tags: android, seekbar

I need a seekbar with markers like:

[image: seekbar with red markers]

I only need a background representing the red markers but the position of those markers need to be changed programmatically.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/seek_divider_1"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/seek_divider_2"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

makes:

[image: result]

To change their position simply set their margin/-left or margin-right accordingly.

It's a 'hack' over anything else. but it should work?

Comment: OK great! Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: How can i do this on runtime...i need to add RED line on seekbar multiply times.
may be at run time program decide to add line on 10sec and 44sec?